# dart add data class in function parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have three methods like these:

```
func1() async {
 ...
 var list = (response['contents'] as List).map((i) => Quotation.fromJson(i)).toList();
 ...
} // has 20 lines

func2() async {
 ...
 var list = (response['contents'] as List).map((i) => Delivery.fromJson(i)).toList();
 ...
} // has 20 lines

func3() async {
 ...
 var list = (response['contents'] as List).map((i) => Discovery.fromJson(i)).toList();
 ...
} // has 20 lines
```

now i would like to add a parameter to generalize the `SomeClass.fromJson(i)`

so the code would be like this

```
generalFunc( someType SomeClass ) async {
 ...
 var list = (response['contents'] as List).map((i) => SomeClass.fromJson(i)).toList();
 ...
}

... call generalFunc(Quotation) // reduce 19 lines
... call generalFunc(Delivery) // reduce 19 lines
... call generalFunc(Discovery) //reduce 19 lines
```

how do i accomplish this? thank you..

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a parameter `someType SomeClass` you are expecting an object of `SomeClass`. if that is what you want, you can declare a parameter of type `dynamic`.

See the code below:

```
generalFunc( generic SomeClassObject ) async {
 ...
 var list = (response['contents'] as List).map((i) => SomeClassObject.fromJson(i)).toList();
 ...
}

... call generalFunc(quotationObject) // reduce 19 lines
... call generalFunc(deliveryObject) // reduce 19 lines
... call generalFunc(discoveryObject) //reduce 19 lines
```

But, if you want to pass a class... well that is impossible. but you can work it out by making the parameter as a selector for the class.

See the code below:

```
enum SomeClass {
  Quotation,
  Delivery,
  Discovery
}

generalFunc({ SomeClass someClass }) async {
  ...
  var list;
  if(someClass == SomeClass.Quotation){
    list = (response['contents'] as List).map((i) => Quotation.fromJson(i)).toList();
  }
  else if(someClass == SomeClass.Discovery) {
    list = (response['contents'] as List).map((i) => Discovery.fromJson(i)).toList();
  }
  else if(someClass == SomeClass.Delivery) {
    list = (response['contents'] as List).map((i) => Delivery.fromJson(i)).toList();
  }
  ...
}

... call generalFunc(someClass: SomeClass.Delivery);
... call generalFunc(someClass: SomeClass.Discovery);
... call generalFunc(someClass: SomeClass.Qoutation);
```